# The submit button should be enabled only when any checkbox is clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm facing the following issue; the submit button should be enabled only when any checkbox is clicked. Using jQuery the code I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var the_terms = $("#pricingTierId");
    the_terms.click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#submitBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<c:if test="${fn:length(incentiveList) gt 0}">
    <input type='button' name="submit" id = "submitBtn" value='Submit Incentives' onClick='execute();' />
</c:if>
```

However in the checkbox code I have the following

```
<td>
    <s:checkbox name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" id="%{pricingTierId}"/>    
</td>
```

my id attribute is defined as `id="%{pricingTierId}"` so I cannot really pass that in the jQuery function as shown above. Please suggest the suitable way

Comment: try adding a class name and attach event using the `$('.class')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). As of **jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Add a class to checkbox and then you can use that class like (since OP is using struts2 `cssClass` is used)

```
<s:checkbox cssClass="yourClass" name="checkboxes[%{#stat.index}]" theme="simple" id="%{pricingTierId}"/>
```

*Code*, Also your code can be converted to single line

```
$('.yourClass').change(function() {
    $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", this.checked == false);
});
```

If You have multiple checkboxes and atleast one should be checked

```
$('.yourClass').change(function() {
    $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", $('.yourClass').is(":checked") == false);
});
```

Also go through [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: HI Im getting 
attribute class invalid for tag checkbox a according to tld and Im using struts2

Comment: @ronan, As you are using struts2 use `cssClass="yourClass"`

Comment: I dont have cssClass yet defined what needs to be used ?

Comment: @ronan, I didn't got you

Comment: Please elaborate what is cssClass since I have not created a csss class in my JSP which should be used in that ?

Comment: Thanks Satpal , I got it , its an attribute itself :)